# Are there any open-source or commercial UIs for a Carte slave server?

Tags: user-interface, pentaho, kettle

We have a number of Kettle jobs we run today using cron jobs (scheduled tasks on Windows).  However, running them like this does not give us any feedback or allow manual control by any but the people who manage the servers on which the jobs run.

I believe the using Carte is the answer to this challenge.  However, I cannot seem to find any UI software other than the full Pentaho suite that give any sort of UI front end to Carte.  Am I missing something?

I found an older post here where the author was asking question because he was building a custom .NET UI to Carte servers...  I'm just looking to use or buy an exiting one.  I don't want to re-invent the wheel if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Carte itself has a very basic status page from which you can examine run logs and run jobs/trans.

You can also manage slave servers from spoon and get the same information. Add carte instances as slave server ( https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0P0/0U0/050/040) 
Double click on the slave server to then view it's run logs.

You may also try something like [Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html). I've never tried this myself, and may require some wiring & config, but it might make Carte's logs more readable.

Comment: I was hoping for a nice looking UI with a little bit of security, maybe alerts, historical trending, that type of thing.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such UI that I am aware of (I'm a developer for Pentaho)

Comment: Security for carte is configurable: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+User+Documentation#CarteUserDocumentation-Security

Comment: Well, that's too bad.  I was looking for a quick win.